# Accessing filtered object values from props (JS/React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a silly question. I'm trying to learn some React and have run into an issue.

I'm using mapStateToProps to return a filtered object matching a specific ID from OwnProps. That part works fine. When I log the state I can see that the correct item was returned. The issue is I'm not sure how to access the values from the Component it's passed to.

Here's my code:

```
const ProductModal = (props) => {
  return (
    <Modal 
        isOpen={props.isOpen}
        onRequestClose={props.handleCloseModal}
        contentLabel="Modal"
        className="modal"
    >
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Item Name Here</p>
    <p>Item Style Here</p>
    <p>Item Sale Here</p>
    </Modal>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {  
  return {
    item: state.filter((item) => {
      return item.id === props.selectedItem
    })
  }
}
const connectedOptionModal = connect(mapStateToProps)(OptionModal);


export default connectedOptionModal;
```

When I log the props in the component I see the items, but not sure how to actually access the values.

When I check Chrome Console this is what I see:

```
item: Array(1)
  0: {
      id: 123456,
      name: t-shirts, 
      style: graphic, 
      sale: false
      }
```

Perhaps there is a way to return a "flattened" state so to eliminate the **0:**?

Apologies if this is a silly question.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The `0` in the console output isn't part of the data. It's merely showing you that the object is at index 0 in the array.

Comment: Are you trying to get just the object? the filter method returns a new array with each element that pass the test. If you want to simply return a single element you can use  [find](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). `find()` returns the first element in the array matching the predicate or `undefined` if nothing is found. This could help avoiding needing to access the array element using `[0]` or similar.

```
const ProductModal = (props) => {
  return (
    <Modal 
        isOpen={props.isOpen}
        onRequestClose={props.handleCloseModal}
        contentLabel="Modal"
        className="modal"
    >
    <h3>Title</h3>
    {props.item &&
      (
        <div>{props.item.name} {props.item.style} {props.item.sale.toString()}</div>
      )
    }
    </Modal>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {  
  return {
    item: state.find((item) => {
      return item.id === props.selectedItem
    })
  }
}
const connectedOptionModal = connect(mapStateToProps)(OptionModal);

export default connectedOptionModal;
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Could you please explain why it doesn't work if I omit {props.item &&  ?? 

If I try to access the values directly with {props.item.name} it throws a type error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: It really depends on the structure of your store and what data is available when this `ProductModal` executes `find()`, but effectively there is a moment in time when there are no items in `state` with an `id` that matches `selectedItem`, which would result in `find()` returning `undefined`. Without the conditional rendering `{props.item && ... }` it attempts to access properties such as `name` of that undefined base object. You can test this by logging `state` and/or the results of find in `mapStateToProps` to see how it is evaluating over time.

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation. That's exactly what was happening. The state is initially empty/undefined when the component renders. This has been a huge help!